# set selection of a Spinner (that uses SpinnerAdapter) programmatically.?

Tags: android, eclipse, adapter, android-spinner

I am using a SpinnerAdpter for my spinner but I don't know how to set a selection in code. the answers I've found are not using a SpinnerAdapter so their solution did not work for me.

here is my adapter:

```
private class PackPricesAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return spinnerPackPrices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return spinnerPackPrices.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text = new TextView(mContext);
        text.setText(spinnerPackPrices.get(position));
        text.setTextSize(13f);
        return text;
    }
}
```

I wanna know how I can set a selection programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a selection on your `Spinner`, after setting the adapter to it, just call:

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Where `position` is the 0-based position of the Spinner item you want to select.